# HTML Center navbar

Tags: html, css

I got a navbar with several levels that i changed acording to this site:https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd

I've looked around on the internet but the solutions they provide (using display:inline-block) did not seem to work out.

Sources i've tryed:

[How to center a navigation bar with CSS or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995405/how-to-center-a-navigation-bar-with-css-or-html)

[how to center css navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368615/how-to-center-css-navigation-bar)

Any help would be appriciated.

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin:auto;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:Futura;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nieuws</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="scouts_taf&toetje.html">Taf & Toetje</a></li>
                <li><a href="scouts_papierwerk.html">Papierwerk</a></li>
                <li><a href="scouts_uniform.html">Uniform</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.scoutsengidsenvlaanderen.be/technieken-databank">Technieken</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="scouts_afspraken.html">Algemeen</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_fotos.php">Foto's</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_inschrijven.html">Inschrijven</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Permekiaan &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Kapoenen &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Kawellen &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Jong-Givers &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Givers &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want the whole navbar to align center. If that's the problem you can use position absolute and from left 50% and translateX(-50%) back.

Comment: Yes i would like the whole navbar to be centered on the page. Could you post an answer with your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to these two classes:

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

The solution was to use `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center;`. But also deleting the `float: left`. Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dibdab/6vvmLyng/1/)

Comment: This kinda achieves what i want but the dropdowns stopped working now.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the original answer turns out I had mistakenly deleted some properties when adding the new ones. Drop downs now work in the Fiddle I used atleast.

Comment: Oke awesome this does what i want it to do. But is it possible to add text next to the bar and center it together?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dibdab/73Lpo3fm/)? If so just need to add the text into the top of the `<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">` tag

Comment: You sir are a first class hero! This is perfect! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

at #primary_nav_wrap

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to center the whole nav.

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not really achieve what i mean. Take a look at the site from Samsung. Thats kinda what i'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the float from the ul and li's and added display: inline-block to the li tags, so I ended up with this:

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

Comment: This kinda achieves what i want but the dropdowns stopped working now.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to `<ul>` make it `<ul class="extra">` and add css to that class `.extra{left:33.33%}`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make few changes in your css classes.

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  text-align:center
}
```

Please check updated [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggLXzZ)

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML Center navbar

with flexbox

```css
#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:Futura;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}

/* flexbox */
#primary_nav_wrap {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;  

  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;       
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul {
  list-style:none;

  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  //padding: 1rem;
  //margin: 1rem;       

  -webkit-align-self: center;       
  align-self: center;
}
/* || flexbox */
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nieuws</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="scouts_taf&toetje.html">Taf & Toetje</a></li>
                <li><a href="scouts_papierwerk.html">Papierwerk</a></li>
                <li><a href="scouts_uniform.html">Uniform</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.scoutsengidsenvlaanderen.be/technieken-databank">Technieken</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="scouts_afspraken.html">Algemeen</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_fotos.php">Foto's</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_inschrijven.html">Inschrijven</a></li>
        <li><a href="scouts_contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Permekiaan &#x25BC;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="dir"><a href="#">Kapoenen &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Kawellen &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Jong-Givers &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dir">
                    <a href="#">Givers &#x25BC;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activiteiten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you add left and right auto margins to primary_nav_wrap?  i.e. add this to CSS:

```html
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```